# Visual C++ 10.0 issue when installing Python module; cl.exe failed with exit status 2 (h5py)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, module, pip, python-3.4

I've been at this for the last 5 hours or so. I've reinstalled a bunch, but essentially I'm trying to install the Python module h5py on a Windows 8.1 machine running Python 3.4.1.

The stack is as follows:

```
Collecting h5py
Using cached h5py-2.6.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from h5py)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from h5py)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for h5py: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for h5py: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\CHARLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bw8g_xls\\h5py\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\CHARLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpbpg7zmwapip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
  copying h5py\highlevel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
  copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
  copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
  copying h5py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  copying h5py\_hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests
  copying h5py\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  copying h5py\tests\old\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
  creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\test_threads.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  copying h5py\tests\hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
  running build_ext
  Autodetection skipped [[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found]
  ********************************************************************************
                         Summary of the h5py configuration

      Path to HDF5: None
      HDF5 Version: '1.8.4'
       MPI Enabled: False
  Rebuild Required: False

  ********************************************************************************
  Executing api_gen rebuild of defs
  Executing cythonize()
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\defs.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_errors.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_objects.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_proxy.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5fd.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5z.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5i.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5r.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\utils.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_conv.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5t.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5s.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5p.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5d.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5a.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5f.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5g.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5l.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5o.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5ds.pyx because it changed.
  Compiling c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5ac.pyx because it changed.
  [ 1/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_conv.pyx
  [ 2/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_errors.pyx
  [ 3/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_objects.pyx
  [ 4/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\_proxy.pyx
  [ 5/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\defs.pyx
  [ 6/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5.pyx
  [ 7/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5a.pyx
  [ 8/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5ac.pyx
  [ 9/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5d.pyx
  [10/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5ds.pyx
  [11/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5f.pyx
  [12/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5fd.pyx
  [13/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5g.pyx
  [14/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5i.pyx
  [15/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5l.pyx
  [16/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5o.pyx
  [17/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5p.pyx
  [18/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5r.pyx
  [19/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5s.pyx
  [20/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5t.pyx
  [21/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\h5z.pyx
  [22/22] Cythonizing c:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\utils.pyx
  building 'h5py.defs' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py
  creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DH5_USE_16_API -D_HDF5USEDLL_ -Ic:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\lzf -Ic:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\windows -IC:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tcc:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\defs.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\defs.obj
  defs.c
  c:\python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
  c:\users\charles kronk\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\api_compat.h(27) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'hdf5.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Running setup.py clean for h5py
Failed to build h5py
Installing collected packages: h5py
  Running setup.py install for h5py: started
    Running setup.py install for h5py: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\CHARLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bw8g_xls\\h5py\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CHARLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-fis5451x-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
    copying h5py\highlevel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
    copying h5py\ipy_completer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
    copying h5py\version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
    copying h5py\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\dims.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\files.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\filters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\selections2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    copying h5py\_hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\_hl
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests
    copying h5py\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_attrs_data.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_dataset.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_dimension_scales.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_group.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5f.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5p.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_h5t.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_selections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\test_slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    copying h5py\tests\old\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\old
    creating build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\test_attribute_create.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\test_dataset_getitem.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\test_dataset_swmr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\test_datatype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\test_dims_dimensionproxy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\test_file.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\test_threads.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    copying h5py\tests\hl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\h5py\tests\hl
    running build_ext
    Autodetection skipped [[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found]
    ********************************************************************************
                           Summary of the h5py configuration

        Path to HDF5: None
        HDF5 Version: '1.8.4'
         MPI Enabled: False
    Rebuild Required: False

    ********************************************************************************
    Executing cythonize()
    building 'h5py.defs' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py
    creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DH5_USE_16_API -D_HDF5USEDLL_ -Ic:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\lzf -Ic:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\windows -IC:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tcc:\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\defs.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\users\charle~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\defs.obj
    defs.c
    c:\python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    c:\users\charles kronk\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bw8g_xls\h5py\h5py\api_compat.h(27) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'hdf5.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
```

Further, the error printed to the command line is:

```
←[31m  Failed building wheel for h5py←[0m
←[31mCommand "C:\Python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__
='C:\\Users\\CHARLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bw8g_xls\\h5py\\setup.py'
;exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '
\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CHARLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-fis5451x-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --com
pile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\CHARLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build
-bw8g_xls\h5py\←[0m
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0.
- Installing Windows SDK 7.1.
- Installing MySQL Connector C 6.0.2 and mklinking it in Program Files (x86).
- Running with pip and easy_install. The same error results both times.
- Installing other modules. I can't repeat the error thus far.
- `pip wheel h5py` fails on the same stack.
- I checked `vcvarsall.bat` and it appears to have the correct configuration (`CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /x64`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! So I did it.

Here's how:

1. I uninstalled all Python versions and deleted all Python-related files, folders, etc. (included PATH variables and packages).
2. I uninstalled all Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Redistributable, Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7, and .NET Framework 4 programs (BE CAREFUL WITH THIS. If you just do the correct files, then you will be fine. I uninstalled other Microsoft programs and ran into several registry errors...).
3. Reinstall [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).
4. Reinstall [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632%20Microsoft%20Visual%20C%20%20%202010%20Redistributable%20Package%20(x64)).
5. Reinstall [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=4422%20Microsoft%20Visual%20C%20%20%202010%20Service%20Pack%201%20Compiler%20Update%20for%20the%20Windows%20SDK%207.1).
6. Reinstall [Python 3.4.0](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/python-3.4.0.amd64.msi) (to `C:\Python34`).
7. Add `C:\Python34` and `C:\Python34\Scripts` to the PATH system variable.
8. Download H5py from this website [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) (specifically `h5py-2.6.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl`).
9. Run `pip3 install h5py-2.6.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl`. This will generate the following:

`Processing c:\python34\h5py-2.6.0-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
    Collecting numpy>=1.6.1 (from h5py==2.6.0)
      Downloading numpy-1.11.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl (7.4MB)
        100% |################################| 7.4MB 46kB/s
    Collecting six (from h5py==2.6.0)
      Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: numpy, six, h5py
    Successfully installed h5py-2.6.0 numpy-1.11.1 six-1.10.0`

Next I ran my program to make sure the import worked correctly, and it did! I hope this helps anyone trying this, just be VERY careful with step (2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to install from the command prompt on my Windows 10 machine.  To bypass this error:

1. I manually downloaded the application from website
2. Extracted it to my C:/"Path where you want to setup the application"
3. Went back into command prompt open up the path where you just extracted the application
4. Run the setup file in the downloaded package from there.

It worked me!!!

Cheers