# Python: Installation kenml error

Tags: python, visual-c++, installation, pip

I am trying to install kenlm for Python with the following command:

```
pip install https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/archive/master.zip
```

At that time I found the following error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Users\\PhyuKhaing\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status2
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Did you searched around the Internet? There are loads of similar problems which come from the binding between the Compiler (from Visual Studio and Python itself). E.g: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10773732/3991125  https://stackoverflow.com/q/12511815/3991125  https://stackoverflow.com/q/39771592/3991125  https://stackoverflow.com/q/39358876/3991125 After reading those Q&As you might get a further idea about how to approach this issue. For sure, you might adapt these solutions to your Python version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual C++ 10.0 issue when installing Python module; cl.exe failed with exit status 2 (h5py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254041/visual-c-10-0-issue-when-installing-python-module-cl-exe-failed-with-exit-sta)